# SceneKit after a few collisions node is going through other nodes

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am making a minigolf game and after a few shots the ball sometimes goes through the floor or wall how can I stop this from happening.

Comment: How are you moving your objects? Moving to a point beyond the physics boundaries will cause this.